# How to create a blank but valid EPS?

Tags: eps

One of our printing applications runs an external program which does some magic and sometimes returns a barcode in EPS format to be printed on the document.

```
if [ ... some magic ]
then
    gnu-barcode -b $1 -c -e code39 -u mm -t 1x3 > $TMP.ps
    ps2epsi $TMP.ps $TMP.eps
    cat $TMP.eps
    rm -f $TMP.eps $TMP.ps
else
    cat /dev/null
fi
```

This works OK. However, it generates an annoying warning on the printing application side about not receiving a valid EPS when the `else ...` runs and we do `cat /dev/null`. I need to return a blank but valid EPS instead of the `cat /dev/null`. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

The EPS format is defined in Adobe Technical note 5002, its available on the web but it moves around so much I won't attempt to post a URL. However, unless you are a PostScript programmer that probably won't help you.

The simplest possible valid EPS would be something like:

```
%!PS-Adobe-2.0 EPSF-3.0
%%BoundingBox:0 0 0 0
```

That's the only required content in an EPSF. Of course, a real printing application might not like a BoundingBox of 0 0 0 0.